# Получить предыдущее значение атрибута data- у выбранной ранее ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить предыдущее значение `data-type` у выбранной ранее ссылки (`.selected`) при клике по новой. Знаю, как реализовать с input, но со списком не получается сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.

```js
$('.cd-gallery-container').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var filter_list_container = $this.children('.cd-filter'),
      filter_values = filter_list_container.find('li:not(.placeholder) a');
  
  filter_list_container.find('li').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected_filter = $(event.target).data('type');
    //добавить класс, выбранной ссылке
    filter_values.removeClass('selected');
    $(event.target).addClass('selected');
    console.log(selected_filter);            
  });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-gallery-container">  
  <nav class="cd-filter">
      <ul>       
          <li>
              <a class="selected" data-type="all" href="#0">Все</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="1" href="#0">1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="2" href="#0">2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="3" href="#0">3</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.cd-gallery-container').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var filter_list_container = $this.children('.cd-filter'),
      filter_values = filter_list_container.find('li:not(.placeholder) a');
  
  filter_list_container.find('li').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected_filter = $(event.target).data('type');

    //сначала узнаем предыдущую .selected, а потом уже добавляем к новой
    var prev = filter_list_container.find('li:not(.placeholder) a.selected').data('type');
    console.log("prev", prev);

    //добавить класс, выбранной ссылке
    filter_values.removeClass('selected');
    $(event.target).addClass('selected');
    console.log("current", selected_filter);            
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-gallery-container">  
  <nav class="cd-filter">
      <ul>       
          <li>
              <a class="selected" data-type="all" href="#0">Все</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="1" href="#0">1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="2" href="#0">2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a data-type="3" href="#0">3</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!:)